# How to get ENV variable when doing Docker Inspect

Tags: docker

I  wonder how I get an Environment variable from docker inspect.

when i run

```
docker inspect -f "{{.Config.Env.PATH}} " 1e2b8689cf06
```

i get the following

```
FATA[0000] template: :1:9: executing "" at <.Config.Env.PATH>: can't evaluate field PATH in type interface {}
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can get directly with a command similar to

```
docker inspect --format '{{ index (index .Config.Env) 1 }}' 797
```

which shows for me

```
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

You will notice that replacing the `1` by  `0` like

```
docker inspect --format '{{ index (index .Config.Env) 0 }}' 797
```

gives

```
DISPLAY=:0
```

In fact I had noticed the following for various `docker inspect` from a more general to a more precise display

```
docker inspect --format '{{ (.NetworkSettings.Ports) }}' 87c
map[8000/tcp:[map[HostIp:0.0.0.0 HostPort:49153]]]
docker inspect --format '{{ ((index .NetworkSettings.Ports "8000/tcp") 0) }}' 87c
[map[HostIp:0.0.0.0 HostPort:49153]]
docker inspect --format '{{ index (index .NetworkSettings.Ports "8000/tcp") 0 }}' 87c
map[HostIp:0.0.0.0 HostPort:49153]
docker inspect --format '{{ (index (index .NetworkSettings.Ports "8000/tcp") 0).HostIp }}' 87c
0.0.0.0
docker inspect --format '{{ (index (index .NetworkSettings.Ports "8000/tcp") 0).HostPort }}' 87c
49153
```

*Note: `docker inspect -f` works and is shorter, of course, I posted the "old" syntax.*

Comment: I created a PR for updating the docs for `docker inspect` https://github.com/docker/docker/pull/13405

Comment: If you want to print out all environment variables use the following command: $docker inspect --format '{{ (index .Config.Env) }}'

Answer (score 26):

This doesn't seem to be possible, you can list the environment variables but not just one.

From the [docker commit doc](https://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/cli/#commit)

```
$ sudo docker inspect -f "{{ .Config.Env }}" c3f279d17e0a
[HOME=/ PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin]

$ sudo docker commit --change "ENV DEBUG true" c3f279d17e0a  SvenDowideit/testimage:version3
f5283438590d

$ sudo docker inspect -f "{{ .Config.Env }}" f5283438590d
[HOME=/ PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin DEBUG=true]
```

You can print them:

```
docker inspect --format='{{range .Config.Env}}{{println .}}{{end}}'
```

(as in)

```
$ docker inspect --format='{{range .Config.Env}}{{println .}}{{end}}' c3fa3ce1622b
HOME=/
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

Add a `grep PATH` and you could get only the `PATH=xxx` value.

---

[user2915097](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2915097/user2915097) mentions [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30342796/how-to-get-env-variable-when-doing-docker-inspect/30343218?noredirect=1#comment48780606_30343218) [jq, a lightweight and flexible command-line JSON processor](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), used in the article "[Docker Inspect Template Magic](http://container-solutions.com/2015/03/docker-inspect-template-magic/) " to format nicely the needed field:

```
docker inspect -f '{{json .State}}' jenkins-data | jq '.StartedAt' 
  "2015-03-15T20:26:30.526796706Z"
```

Comment: you can also use the jq tool https://stedolan.github.io/jq/ like in this example from http://container-solutions.com/2015/03/docker-inspect-template-magic/ `docker inspect -f '{{json .State}}' jenkins-data | jq` shows then `'.StartedAt'
"2015-03-15T20:26:30.526796706Z"`to format nicely the needed field

Comment: @user2915097 Interesting. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 13):

A very convenient option that doesn't require any external tools is:

```
docker exec 1e2b8689cf06 sh -c 'echo $PATH'
```

Admittedly this is not using `docker inspect`, but still..

Comment: Indeed not using `inspect` but, still : this answer is very simple, explicit -- we see the name of the var (PATH) we are looking for and  not some magic index -- and it's understandable without diving in GO pattern language.

Comment: In this exact same way if you want to get ALL the environmental variables just replace ```echo $PATH``` with ```printenv```

Answer (score 11):

```
docker inspect --format='{{range .Config.Env}}{{println .}}{{end}}' CONTAINER-NAME | grep -P "^YOUR_VAR=" | sed 's/[^=]*=//'
```

This solution requires `grep`(with -P option), `sed` and ability to pipeline them but solves 2 problems which most of the other solutions do not.

Firstly, it performs exact match on variable name. For example if you have following variables:

```
YOUR_VAR=value
ANOTHER_YOUR_VAR=value2
OTHER_VAR=YOUR_VAR
```

You will properly receive `value`.

Secondly, it properly handles cases where variable value contains `=` characters. For example:

```
REBEL_OPTS=-Drebel.stats=false
```

Will properly get you `-Drebel.stats=false` instead of `false`.

Answer (score 7):

For those looking for a ***template-only*** solution using only **docker inspect** (when you can't just shell out and grep, etc.), the following example works (as of docker 1.11+):

```
> docker inspect -f '{{range $index, $value := .Config.Env}}{{if eq (index (split $value "=") 0) "SOME_VAR" }}{{range $i, $part := (split $value "=")}}{{if gt $i 1}}{{print "="}}{{end}}{{if gt $i 0}}{{print $part}}{{end}}{{end}}{{end}}{{end}}' *container_name*
```

- *it even handles environment variables with extra '='*

Example container:

```
> docker run -d -e --name sleeper SOME_VAR=key=value alpine:3.4 -sh 'sleep 9999'
```

Extract `SOME_VAR` with:

```
> docker inspect -f '{{range $index, $value := .Config.Env}}{{if eq (index (split $value "=") 0) "SOME_VAR" }}{{range $i, $part := (split $value "=")}}{{if gt $i 1}}{{print "="}}{{end}}{{if gt $i 0}}{{print $part}}{{end}}{{end}}{{end}}{{end}}' sleeper
```

Answer (score 4):

I find it better to parse for the environment variable **name** your interested than relying on index.

```
echo $(docker inspect --format '{{ .Config.Env }}' mysql) |  tr ' ' '\n' | grep MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD | sed 's/^.*=//'
```

Answer (score 4):

Docker formatting options are quite limited, [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) is much more powerful:

```
docker inspect 1e2b8689cf06 | jq '.[] | .Config.Env[] | select(test("^PATH=*"))'
```

or combine Docker format with jq while passing only Env variables to jq:

```
docker inspect -f '{{json .Config.Env }}' 1e2b8689cf06 | jq '.[] | select(test("^PATH=*"))'
```

Assuming there's a `printenv` in the container, you can use simple `grep`:

```
docker exec -i 1e2b8689cf06 printenv | grep -oP '(?<=PATH=).*'
```

`-o` would omit matching `PATH=` part from result. The syntax is much easier to read than the template magic.

Comment: `jq` is probably be best approach. To get the value, one could use `jq '.[] | .Config.Env[] | select(test("^PATH=*")) | split("=") | .[1]'`

Answer (score 2):

If you want want to be able to check success of operation you could go with:

```
(
for env in $(docker inspect -f '{{range .Config.Env}}{{println .}}{{end}}' ${2}); do
    if [[ "${env}" == "${1}"* ]]; then
        echo ${env#${1}=}
        exit 0
    fi
done
exit 1
)
```

This will open a subshell and return depending if found:

```
$ docker-extract PATH docker_image || echo not found
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
$ docker-extract NON_EXISTENT_ENV docker_image || echo not found
not found
$
```

Comment: that's an great way, good to understand and to reuse. maybe you should have to add the information that the above code is shell script and is the content of docker-extract(.sh).

Answer (score 0):

Print all env variables by specifying a docker **container** name:

```
docker exec <container-name> /bin/sh -c 'printenv'
```

Print all env variables by specifying a docker **service** name:

```
docker-compose exec <service-name> /bin/sh -c 'printenv'
```

Print a specific variable (PATH) by using docker **container** name:

```
docker exec <container-name> /bin/sh -c 'printenv' | grep '^PATH='
```

gives:

> PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin

Print a specific variable **value** (PATH) by using docker **container** name:

```
docker exec <container-name> /bin/sh -c 'printenv' | grep '^PATH=' | cut -d= -f2-
```

gives:

> /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin

Same examples as above but for the docker **service** name:

Specific env variable:

```
docker-compose exec <service-name> /bin/sh -c 'printenv' | grep '^PATH='
```

Specific env variable **value**:

```
docker-compose exec <service-name> /bin/sh -c 'printenv' | grep '^PATH=' | cut -d= -f2-
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `docker exec` in combination with `printenv`. It should be on the most base images.

```bash
$ docker exec <container> printenv <desired_variable>
```

example

```bash
$ docker exec postgres printenv PGDATA
$ /var/lib/postgresql/data
```