# How can I grab exposed port from inspecting docker container?

Tags: sed, grep, docker, dockerfile

Assuming that I start a docker container with the following command

```
docker run -d --name my-container -p 1234 my-image
```

and running `docker ps` shows the port binding for that image is...

```
80/tcp, 443 /tcp. 0.0.0.0:32768->1234/tcp
```

Is there a way that I can use `docker inspect` to grab the port that is assigned to be mapped to `1234` (in this case, 32768)?

Similar to parsing and grabbing the IP address using the following command...

```
IP=$(docker inspect -f "{{ .Networksettings.IPAddress }} my-container)
```

I want to be able to do something similar to the following

```
ASSIGNED_PORT=$(docker inspect -f "{{...}} my-container)
```

I am not sure if there is a way to do this through Docker, but I would imagine there is some command line magic (grep,sed,etc) that would allow me to do something like this.

When I run `docker inspect my-container` and look at the `NetworkSettings`...I see the following

```
"NetworkSettings": {
        ...
        ...
        ...
        "Ports": {
            "1234/tcp": [
                {
                    "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                    "HostPort": "32768"
                }
            ],
            "443/tcp": null,
            "80/tcp": null
        },
        ...
        ...
    },
```

In this case, I would want it to find HostPort without me telling it anything about port 1234 (it should ignore 443 and 80 below it) and return `32768`.

Comment: I do not have a docker prompt handy, what gives `docker inspect -f '{{ .NetworkSettings.Port }}' container_id` (and we will refine) , maybe you can try `docker inspect --format '{{ (index (index .NetworkSettings.Ports "1234/tcp") 0).HostPort }}`container_id'

Comment: see my answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30342796/how-to-get-env-variable-when-doing-docker-inspect/30353018#30353018

Comment: @user2915097 `NetworkSettings.Port` wont work (see the edit I made above to the output of `docker inspect`.

Comment: @user2915097 I have updated my question above. I don't want to tell it `1234` as I might not know it.

Comment: When docker inspect goes deeper, it needs to find what is under 1234/tcp, of course you can always hack with jq https://stedolan.github.io/jq/ and pipe grep

Comment: does `docker port my-container 1234` help? http://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/port/

Answer (score 8):

Execute the command: `docker inspect --format="{{json .Config.ExposedPorts }}" src_python_1`

Result: `{"8000/tcp":{}}`

Proof (using `docker ps`):

```
e5e917b59e15        src_python:latest   "start-server"         22 hours ago        Up 22 hours         0.0.0.0:8000->8000/tcp                                        src_python_1
```

Comment: Could your update this to grab JUST the port so I can assign it to a variable?

Comment: @TheJediCowboy, now the issue is how to parse the result into a Shell script array, because a container may have lots of exposed ports. I will take a look into it. What I know so far is that `docker insepct --format` return results using the [Go Language Template package](http://golang.org/pkg/text/template/).

Comment: Actually, this grabs the exposed port number from the service WITHIN the container - it doesn't show you the HostPort, i.e. how to access the service from the docker machine IP. The solutions by Alen Komljen (https://stackoverflow.com/a/31655055/6295318) and Travis Reeder (https://stackoverflow.com/a/48965777/6295318) are the correct anwsers to OP's question.

Answer (score 4):

It is not easy as with ip address as one container can have multiple ports, some exposed and some not, but this will get it:

```
sudo docker inspect name | grep HostPort | sort | uniq | grep -o [0-9]*
```

If more than one port is exposed it will be displayed on a new line.

Answer (score 3):

There are two good options depending on your taste: `docker port my-container 1234 | grep -o [0-9]*$` and `docker inspect --format='{{(index (index .NetworkSettings.Ports "1234/tcp") 0).HostPort}}' my-container`

Answer (score 1):

Using jq:

```
docker inspect --format="{{json .}}" my-container | jq '.NetworkSettings.Ports["1234/tcp"][0].HostPort'
```

Change 1234 with the port you specified in `docker run`.

Answer (score 1):

The above answers were close and put me on the right track, but I kept getting the following error:

> Template parsing error: template: :1: unexpected "/" in operand

I found the answer here: https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/27592

This is what finally worked for me:

```
docker inspect --format="{{(index (index .NetworkSettings.Ports \"80/tcp\") 0).HostPort}}" $INSTANCE_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used both `docker inspect <container>` and `docker inspect <container>| jq` combination to strip ports.

In below example I am looking at **dsb-server** container and port I am looking for is **8080/tcp**

```
docker ps

CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                                                         COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                                                NAMES
98b4bec33ba9        xxxxx:dsbv3   "./docker-entrypoint."   6 days ago          Up 6 days           8009/tcp, 0.0.0.0:4848->4848/tcp, 8181/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9013->8080/tcp   dsb-server
```

to strip ports

```
docker inspect dsb-server| jq -r '.[].NetworkSettings.Ports."8080/tcp"[].HostPort'
```

9013

```
docker inspect --format='{{(index (index .NetworkSettings.Ports "8080/tcp") 0).HostPort}}'
```

9013