# Docker Port Detection

Tags: docker

I have a docker container that listens on a socket, lets say its udp port 20000. (this is iot udp data coming in)

This app can (and should) be loadbalanced.

I publish it to my docker host and expose the port. Docker assigns some random port on the docker host.

I need to add this container to the pool on my loadbalancer, which sits outside of the docker network.

How do I automate this? Any time a new instance of this container starts I need to add it to the pool. When it dies I need to remove it from the pool.

Comment: you probably want to subscribe to docker events and then inspect the image for port when you get the start/stop events and act appropriately with your loadbalancer

Comment: if you start your container with `--name mycontainer_app` you can just `docker inspect mycontainer_app` and more precisely something like `docker inspect --format '{{ (index (index .NetworkSettings.Ports "20000/tcp") 0).HostPort }} mycontainer_app` which should give you this port

Comment: see my answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30342796/how-to-get-env-variable-when-doing-docker-inspect/30353018#30353018 for more details

Comment: In my answer, this command output was `49153`

Answer (score 0):

The pattern which worked for me is to use 2 pieces:

1. [Registrator](http://gliderlabs.com/registrator/latest/), which detects containers as they go on-line and register them in a kind of service registry (e.g. [Consul](https://www.consul.io/)).
2. Load-balancer that is aware (watches) of services registered and changing its configuration accordingly. In my particular case it was [HAProxy](http://www.haproxy.org/) supported by [Consul Template](https://github.com/hashicorp/consul-template), which did a great job in automating all this stuff.

In general, this pattern can vary in details, but usually it will be something like that.