# I can't connect to Rabbitmq server port 5672

Tags: docker, rabbitmq, symfony

with this command

```
php bin/console rabbitmq:consumer -w upload_picture
```

I have this problem                                       .

```
 [ErrorException]
stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to tcp://localhost:5672 (Aucune
 connexion n'a pu etre établie car l'ordinateur cible lÆa expressÚment
 refusée.
```

So I can't connect to server rabbitmq

config.yml

```
old_sound_rabbit_mq:
connections:
    default:
        host:     'localhost' # hostname and port of the rabbitmq server
        port:     5672
        user:     'guest'
        password: 'guest'
        vhost:    '/'
        lazy:     true # a lazy connection avoids unnecessary connections to the broker on every request
        connection_timeout: 3
        read_write_timeout: 3
        keepalive: false
        heartbeat: 0
producers:
    upload_picture:
        connection:       default # connects to the default connection configured above
        exchange_options: {name: 'upload_picture', type: direct}
consumers:
    upload_picture:
        connection:       default # connects to the default connection configured above
        exchange_options: {name: 'upload_picture', type: direct}
        queue_options:    {name: 'upload_picture'}
        callback:         upload_picture_service # the UploadPictureConsumer defined below
```

Comment: your command connects to localhost, if your port 5672 is not published by the container on the host, it will fail.  Show `docker port your_rabbitmq_container` , here is the doc https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/port/

Comment: On the rabbitmq machine, type `netstat -a` and make sure it is listening on that port and not only on a unix socket.

Comment: the port 5672 not exist in the list ( netstat -a )

Comment: with is command **docker ps**                                                                 
    7c01193b2f74        projecttest_queue    "docker-entrypoint..."   24 hours ago        Up 5 hours          4369/tcp, 5671/tcp, 25672/tcp, 0.0.0.0:55672->5672/tcp, 0.0.0.0:32768->15672/tcp   projecttest_queue_1

Comment: replace localhost with the name of the container (from your comment seems projecttest_queue)

Comment: It does not work    stream_socket_client(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed:

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on your comment

```
7c01193b2f74 projecttest_queue "docker-entrypoint..." 24 hours ago Up 5 hours 4369/tcp, 5671/tcp, 25672/tcp, 0.0.0.0:55672->5672/tcp, 0.0.0.0:32768->15672/tcp
```

The port that the project is listening on is 55672 - see `0.0.0.0:55672->5672/tcp`

Therefore you need to update your php project to connect to `localhost:55672` instead of just `localhost:5672`

Comment: Unfortunately the same problem with 55672

Comment: In that case check what IP the rabbitmq server is listening on. If the `config.yml` you provided is from the rabbitmq server, then you need to change the host to `0.0.0.0` so that rabbitmq **DOES NOT** listen on `localhost` because it will not be accessible from outside the docker container

Answer (score 0):

You can find directly the port you need to connect with

`docker inspect --format '{{ (index (index .NetworkSettings.Ports "5672/tcp") 0).HostPort }}' rabbitmq_container`

See [How to get ENV variable when doing Docker Inspect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30342796/how-to-get-env-variable-when-doing-docker-inspect/30353018#30353018) for more details on how to get a specific value from `docker inspect`