# bash regular expressions to get docker container port number

Tags: bash, docker

So I'm trying to get a specific port number from my docker cluster, this is done because I need the port later on.

When I do docker-compose ps I get the following output

```
contaimer_db_1            docker-entrypoint.sh mysqld      Up      3306/tcp
container_node_1          /usr/bin/supervisord -n          Up      0.0.0.0:3902->3902/tcp
container_php_1           docker-php-entrypoint php-fpm    Up      9000/tcp
container_redis_1         docker-entrypoint.sh redis ...   Up      6379/tcp
```

What I would like to get is the port number just from the container_node_1 3902

So far I got

```
docker-compose ps | grep "[ :]\?[[:digit:]]\{4\}"
```

But this will get all ports since they have 4 numbers in a row. How would I change this to make sure it will only get the node port?

If it's any help, the node container will always show up as 0.0.0.0:1234->1234

Comment: Only for `container_node_1` is what you want to get?

Comment: Yeah, I would prefer getting just the number port of container_node_1 "3902"

Comment: try `awk -F'[/ >]' '/container_node_1/{print $(NF-1)}'`

Comment: Running `docker-compose ps | awk -F'[/ >]' '/financegilde830_node_1/{print $(NF-1)}` will only return `tcp`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `Awk` alone and calling `split()` function twice,

```
docker-compose ps | awk '$1=="container_node_1"{n=split($NF,arr1,"->"); split(arr1[n],arr2,"/"); print arr2[1]}'
```

will give you the port number as intended. This will work on *any* `POSIX` compliant `Awk` installed.

If you have `GNU Awk` installed, you can use its [`gensub()`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html) function to do the regex match and extract the port number,

```
docker-compose ps | awk '$1=="container_node_1"{print gensub(/.*->([[:digit:]]+)\/(.+)$/,"\\1","g",$NF)}'
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/faJw5D/1) for the regex used inside.

Comment: You sir are my saviour today :), will accept the answer once the 5 minutes have passed

Comment: @killstreet: Happy to be of help!

Comment: You only need a single split `split($NF,arr1,/(->|\/)/);print arr1[2]`

Answer (score 3):

I would rather use `docker inspect`

example

docker-compose ps

### Name                          Command               State         Ports

dockerpartkeepr_database_1    docker-entrypoint.sh mysqld      Up      3306/tcp
dockerpartkeepr_partkeepr_1   docker-php-entrypoint apac ...   Up      0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp

So I will try to get the port linked to 80

`docker inspect --format '{{ (index (index .NetworkSettings.Ports "80/tcp") 0).HostPort }}' dockerpartkeepr_partkeepr_1`

which will show

`80`

see my answer [How to get ENV variable when doing Docker Inspect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30342796/how-to-get-env-variable-when-doing-docker-inspect/30353018#30353018)

for more explanations

Comment: This will only work when you know the port used, my ports can be variable. Should have added that to my question probably.

Answer (score 0):

In the script, I needed to find out the external PostgreSQL port in Docker.
I did it this way, maybe not correctly, but it’s short and simpler.

```
ps -ax |grep docker |grep $IP_Postgres |grep 0.0.0.0 |awk '{print $11}'
```

Where IP_Postgres is the IP address of PostgreSQL in the container, for example 172.18.0.x.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Docker and Docker Compose include a `port` command so you don't need to parse the `ps` output, e.g.:

```bash
$ docker compose port node 3902
0.0.0.0:3902
```

You do need to know the container's internal port number, but for a given service, you often know that. To extract the port after the IP address, you can do that directly in the shell:

```bash
$ port="$(docker compose port node 3902)"
$ echo "${port##*:}"
3902
```