# Docker image environment variable dependencies

Tags: docker, deployment, amazon-ecs

Is there an accepted best practice for documenting/tagging a docker image with the list of environment variable it requires?

When we want to deploy a docker image how do we find the list of env. variables it requires programmatically?

Answer (score 1):

you can launch the image with a

`docker run -it your_image`

and then check with

`docker inspect --format '{{ .Config.Env }}' container_name_or_id`

you will get an array, something like

`[DISPLAY=:0 PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin LANG=fr_FR.UTF-8 LANGUAGE=fr_FR:en LC_ALL=fr_FR.UTF-8 DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive HOME=/home/gg WINEARCH=win32 WINEPREFIX=/home/gg/.wine_captvty]`

To get just an element from this array, you can check

[How to get ENV variable when doing Docker Inspect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30342796/how-to-get-env-variable-when-doing-docker-inspect/30353018#30353018)

You can also just do

`docker run -it your_image`

and then

`docker exec -it your_container_just_launched env`

Comment: Thanks.
This option will give environment variable from running container. But for the container to start, it would require few environment variables. So I should know this beforehand. The question is how.

Comment: When you only have an image `docker history --no-trunc myimage` will show the lines like `ENV abc 123` or other syntax `ENV abc=123` so you will get them, and you should know beforehand that image1 will be launched with `docker run -e...` or such, so you should know all environment variables