# docker inspect: how to select only certain keys from range

Tags: docker, go

I created an docker image that has few labels, here is my Dockerfile section on LABELS:

```
grep LABEL Dockerfile

LABEL "css1"="/var/www/css1"
LABEL "css2"="/var/www/css2"
LABEL "img"="/var/www/img"
LABEL "js"="/var/www/js"
```

Then:

```
docker image inspect --format='{{.Config.Labels}}' labels-test

map[css1:/var/www/css1 css2:/var/www/css2 img:/var/www/img js:/var/www/js]
```

I need to get for example all labels starting with *css*. This is as far as i was able to figure:

```
docker image inspect --format='{{range $k,$v:=.Config.Labels}}{{$k}}:{{$v}} {{end}}' labels-test

css1:/var/www/css1 css2:/var/www/css2 img:/var/www/img js:/var/www/js
```

Desired output would be:

```
css1:/var/www/css1 css2:/var/www/css2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Go template functions are available in golang docco](https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/#hdr-Functions)

`eq` can test if `arg1` == `arg2`.
 
`printf "%.3s" $k` will give you the first 3 chars of a string.

```
docker image inspect \
  --format='{{ range $k,$v:=.Config.Labels }}{{ if eq (printf "%.3s" $k) "css" }}{{ $k }}:{{ $v }} {{end}}{{end}}' \
  IMAGE
```

You might want to look at the querying the Docker API [images endpoint](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.32/#operation/ImageInspect) `/images/IMAGE/json` directly or processing the JSON output somewhere if you need to do any more advanced processing:

```
docker image inspect \
  --format='{{json .Config.Labels}}' \
  IMAGE
```

Comment: can this handle regex somehow?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, but I don't know a whole lot of Go. It's possible to add custom functions if you have access to the Go code but it looks like we are stuck with whatever Docker provides for `--format`.

Comment: How can I get the numbers of entries that match (from my example desired output would be 2)?

Comment: pipe the output into `grep -c` or `wc -l` if you use a new line as a delimiter. The other option would be to add a counter that increments inside the `if`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like

`docker inspect --format='{{index (index (.Config.Labels)).css1 }}' labels-test`

which shows for me

`/var/www/css1`

and also

`docker inspect --format='{{index (index (.Config.Labels)).css2 }}' labels-test`

which shows for me

`/var/www/css2`

See my previous answer on that subject
[How to get ENV variable when doing Docker Inspect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30342796/how-to-get-env-variable-when-doing-docker-inspect/30353018#30353018)

Edit

The following gives exactly what you ask for

`docker inspect --format='{{index (index (.Config.Labels)).css1 }} {{index (index (.Config.Labels)).css2 }} labels-test`

as i get

`/var/www/css1 /var/www/css2`

Comment: I tried to use index in the beginning but could figure out how to do css* for example:
    docker image inspect --format '{{ index .Config.Labels "css" }}' labels-test