# Where I can find all variables of docker image

Tags: docker, yaml, dockerfile

Where I can find variables or docker image after pulling - like for `mongo` image there are variables like  `MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME` but I have to find them on web resources. Is there some sort of command to show variables like `--help` or example `yaml` file or any file that has information about these variables?

or maybe at least printing whole `dockerfile` but with filled variables placeholders if they were set along the way...

Comment: Usually running `printenv` in your terminal shows you all env variables. So maybe you could run this inside your container?

Comment: ** It might depend on what the mongo image is built on top of.. It might not work, hmm

Comment: @DimitarHristov yes if I will not set some variable (which could be crucial) then it's not listed, thank you for answer but it's not it

Answer (score 4):

I would use `docker exec` to get a shell inside the container and use `printenv` like below:

```sh
❯ docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                              COMMAND                  CREATED        STATUS         PORTS                                             NAMES
a35281f615b1   adminer                            "entrypoint.sh docke…"   2 months ago   Up 6 hours     0.0.0.0:8090->8080/tcp, :::8090->8080/tcp         data-mock_adminer_1
016b075fee00   quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:latest   "/opt/jboss/tools/do…"   2 months ago   Up 5 seconds   8443/tcp, 0.0.0.0:80->8080/tcp, :::80->8080/tcp   docker-scripts_keycloak_1
0409951e3c5f   mysql:5.7                          "docker-entrypoint.s…"   2 months ago   Up 5 seconds   3306/tcp, 33060/tcp                               docker-scripts_mysql_1
❯ docker exec -it 016 /bin/bash
bash-4.4$ printenv
LAUNCH_JBOSS_IN_BACKGROUND=1
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING=false
HOSTNAME=016b075fee00
JDBC_MARIADB_VERSION=2.5.4
DB_USER=keycloak
container=oci
JDBC_POSTGRES_VERSION=42.2.5
DB_ADDR=mysql
```

Comment: yes but when I will not set some variable that I should have set (optional variable) then this variable is not listed...

Answer (score 1):

@HenriDeBel's answer is fine but requires spinning a container (with `docker run` or so) from the image.

To avoid this (if the environment variables you are interested in have been added using `ENV` commands), note that you can just rely on `docker inspect` to list these environment variables.

For example, the following command (inspired by [this answer by @VonC − *How to get ENV variable when doing Docker Inspect*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30343218/9164010)) can be used to get them in a JSON format:

```sh
$ sudo docker inspect -f '{{json .Config.Env}}' coqorg/base:4.07.1-flambda
["PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin","OPAM_VERSION=2.0.8","NJOBS=2","OPAMPRECISETRACKING=1","COMPILER=4.07.1+flambda","OCAMLFIND_VERSION=1.8.1","DUNE_VERSION=2.8.5","ZARITH_VERSION=1.12"]
```

Comment: yes but when I will not set some variable that I should have set (optional variable) then this variable is not listed...

Comment: I'm unsure to get what you mean exactly: if you don't set a variable, how could you get a value for it?

Comment: Anyway, if you are scripting something in bash, maybe you are looking for something like `"${VARIABLE_NAME:-default value if unset}"`?

Comment: according to https://github.com/docker-library/docs/tree/master/mongo if I will set variable `MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME` and others new DB user will be created and after running your command `docker inspect -f '{{json .Config.Env}}' mongo` there is no such variable in output `["PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin","GOSU_VERSION=1.12","JSYAML_VERSION=3.13.1","GPG_KEYS=20691EEC35216C63CAF66CE1656408E390CFB1F5","MONGO_PACKAGE=mongodb-org","MONGO_REPO=repo.mongodb.org","MONGO_MAJOR=4.4","MONGO_VERSION=4.4.6"]` I would like to see this variable if it's possible, thx

Comment: OK I see, but then I don't think what you're looking for can be automated: the variable you are interested is just *an input variable* from [mongo's docker-entrypoint.sh](https://github.com/docker-library/mongo/blob/791d400b9e84a298356b78db01956d98db973b9d/4.4/docker-entrypoint.sh#L212). So unless you write an ad-hoc bash-script parser, the only solution I see is that you hardcode in your code, the variables you are interested in, probably taken from the documentation of each base image.

Comment: thank you probably this feature will be added to docker some day...

Comment: I don't think so: the feature you'd want is mostly decorelated from Docker: just assume the entrypoint of a base image you are interested in is a Java program or so, and reads a specific environment variable to behave differently if it is set. How could you extract that piece of information from the compiled binary that serves as an entrypoint? Programmatically speaking, I don't see how. Practically speaking, one should just browse the base image documentation (if there is some :)